# Prove or disprove this statement. If G is a group in which every proper subgroup is cyclic, then G is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

I want someone to check my proof.
Suppose every proper subgroup is cyclic,but G is not cyclic.
Since subgroup is cyclic,It generator must exist in subgroup.
Then all element in subgroup exist in G;it included the generator of subgroup.
then G has generator and cyclic 
contradict my assumetion 
therefore if every proper subgroup is cyclic G is cyclic

Comment: Try $S_3$.  Only proper subgroups have order $1,2$ or $3$.

Comment: You cannot deduce "then G has generator...", because you only know that a generator of a _subgroup_ exists in $G$. Did you try looking for some examples?